# Retain null in nested JMESPath query with Ansible

Tags: ansible, jinja2, jmespath

I make an API call in ansible and analyse the response. A repro:

```yaml
---
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false

  vars:
    response: {
        "results": [
          {
            "item": "server1",
            "json": {
              "data": null,         # <----- here's the problem
              "ok": true
            },
            "status": 200
          },
          {
            "item": "server2",
            "json": {
              "data": [
                {
                  "id": 7,
                  "name": "Production5"
                }
              ],
              "ok": true
            },
            "status": 200
          }
        ]
      }

  tasks:
    - debug:
        msg: "{{ response.results | community.general.json_query(_query) }}"
      vars:
        _query: "[].json.data[*].id | []"
```

Which yields:

```bash
TASK [debug] *********************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": [
        7
    ]
}
```

But I actually need:

```bash
TASK [debug] *********************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": [
        null,                    # <-----
        7
    ]
}
```

I want to keep the `null` so the input and output arrays have the same length, as this is important in future tasks.

I tried converting the null without success, e.g.: `([].json.data || [])[*].id` and `not_null([].json.data, '[]')[*].id`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The filter [*json_query*](https://jmespath.org/specification.html) is not capable of doing this, I'm afraid. Try [*Jinja*](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/latest/templates/) instead

```yaml
  result: |
    {% filter from_yaml %}
    {% for i in response.results|map(attribute='json.data') %}
    - {{ i.0.id|default('null') }}
    {% endfor %}
    {% endfilter %}
```

gives what you want

```yaml
  result:
    - null
    - 7
```

Optionally, use *json_query*, create the lists of values, and map the value. The below expression gives the same result

```yaml
  result: "{{ response.results|
              json_query('[].[json.data[0].id, item]')|
              map('first') }}"
```

---

- Example of a complete playbook for testing

```yaml
- hosts: localhost

  vars:

    response:
      results:
        - item: server1
          json:
            data: null
            ok: true
          status: 200
        - item: server2
          json:
            data:
              - {id: 7, name: Production5}
            ok: true
          status: 200

    result1: |
      {% filter from_yaml %}
      {% for i in response.results|map(attribute='json.data') %}
      - {{ i.0.id|default('null') }}
      {% endfor %}
      {% endfilter %}

    result2: "{{ response.results|
                 json_query('[].[json.data[0].id, item]')|
                 map('first') }}"

  tasks:

    - debug:
        var: result1
    - debug:
        var: result2
```

Comment: Thanks! I put that into a `debug:` module but got `"Unexpected templating type error occurred: sequence item 4: expected str instance, int found.` Am I using it correctly?

Comment: I added an example of a complete playbook for testing your data *response* copied from your question. I can't see any item *4* in this data. You must be talking about something else.

Comment: Thanks. I copied your latest code verbatim into a new playbook and put it in a different directory, all on its own, no other config files, etc. I got the same error: `An unhandled exception occurred while templating ... sequence item 4: expected str instance, int found.`. I'm using ansible 2.14.6 on ubuntu 22. Weird! Thank you for your help regardless, I really appreciate it.

Comment: I just tried this on a different machine, debian 12, and it worked. So problem must be my local configuration, but I have no idea what it could be. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Hi Vladimir, I managed to get it working with `json_query` by using an intermediate transformation step, then projecting to what I really want. Your code helped put me in the right direction. As always, thank you so much for your help.

Comment: Good catch! You can simplify it by creating a list `[item, json.data[0].id]` instead of the dictionary and *map* the last items. I added this example. Thank you for the comments!

Answer (score 1):

@VladimirBotka's solution is obviously good, but doesn't work in my environment (see comments under his answer)... maybe a python versioning issue.

But I managed to get it to work using an intermediate transformation:

```yaml
tasks:
  - debug:
      msg: "{{ response.results |
               json_query('[].{item:item,id:(json.data[].id)[0]}') |
               map(attribute='id') }}"
```

Which gives

```
[
  null,
  7
]
```